# transition matrix of two players - Markov Chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose now that two players ($\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{B}$), each having \$2, agree to keep playing the
game and betting \$1 at a time until one player is broke. The probability of $\textbf{A}$ winning a
single bet is 1/3, so $\textbf{B}$ wins the bet with probability 2/3. The number of dollars that player A
has before each bet (0, 1, 2, 3, or 4) provides the states of a Markov chain. i.e., states are 0, 1, 2, 3,  4.

I know the transition matrix which is given [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070287678) as follows:
\begin{bmatrix}
1  &  0  &   0   &  0  &   0 \\
2/3  &  0   &  1/3  &  0  &   0 \\
0  &  2/3  &  0  &  1/3  &   0 \\
0  &  0  &  2/3  &  0  &   1/3 \\
0  &  0  &  0 &  0  &   1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Now my question is: how can I construct this transition matrix?  I don't understand whether it is unique or not.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you say what the states are?  That's always how you start.

Comment: @ saulspatz  Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entry in row $i$ column $j$ is $p_{ij}$, the probability that if the state is in state $i$ at step $n$ it will be in state $j$ at time $n+1$.  So if the chain is in state $0$, it will remain in state $0$, because $\mathbf{A}$ is broke and the game is over.  So, $p_{00}=1$ and $p_{0i}=0$ for $i\neq0$.  That takes care of the first row.  The last row is similar, because the game also ends if $\mathbf{B}$ is broke.

Each of the other rows express the fact that $\mathbf{A}$'s bankroll increases by $1$ with probability $\frac13$ or decreases by $1$ with probability $\frac23$, and there are no other possibilities.

Comment: @ saulspatz  Thanks. I got it now. It's better to show it using diagram. Then construct matrix. That is easier much.

Comment: @Sam That's true, at least in small cases, but it's not so easy to draw diagrams on the computer, at least, not for me.  If this answer solved your problem, you should accept it so that it no longer shows as unresolved.